# Displaying "One Time" Notification in Plugins

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin, session, notices

In WordPress's backend, you can add notifications and errors using HTML that looks like this

```
<div class="updated error">
    <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A bad thing happened!', 'your-text-domain' );?></p>
</div>
```

You can add these notices using the `admin_notices` hook.

```
add_action( 'admin_notices', function(){
    ?>
        <div class="updated error">
            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A bad thing happened!', 'your-text-domain' );?></p>
        </div>         
    <?php
} );
```

Does WordPress have a mechanism, or is there a "generally considered good" third party practice, that would allow you to set a "one time" notice?  The scenario I'm thinking of is

1. User posts a form
2. For handling code does stuff, notifies user
3. New page loads with notice
4. If users reloads or re-navigates to page (back button), message does not display again

Other application frameworks I've used have a session abstraction to handle things like this.  I'm curious if WordPress has something similar, or if there's a generally accepted way to do this, or if WordPress plugins Just Don't Do This™.

Comment: Here's a logic I am following for my plugins. I assign an option for all notices update_option(), now when I need to add an admin notice after a specific operation with code, I update that option, when the WP admin loads, I call admin_notices which pulls everything currently in the option, and at shutdown just clear everything. let me know if that was not clear I can answer with a code sample.

Answer (score 2):

The idea is that you need to `save_errors` or update the option that has the errors/notices whenever you want. As soon as its output once by `admin_notices` it will be cleared.

```
/**
 * Sample_Notice_Handling
 */
class Sample_Notice_Handling {

    public static $_notices  = array();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'admin_notices', array( $this, 'output_errors' ) );
        add_action( 'shutdown', array( $this, 'save_errors' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Add an error message
     */
    public static function add_error( $text ) {
        self::$_notices[] = $text;
    }

    /**
     * Save errors to an option
     */
    public function save_errors() {
        update_option( 'custom_notices', self::$_notices );
    }

    /**
     * Show any stored error messages
     */
    public function output_errors() {
        $errors = maybe_unserialize( get_option( 'custom_notices' ) );

        if ( ! empty( $errors ) ) {

            echo '<div id="mc_errors" class="error notice is-dismissible">';

            foreach ( $errors as $error ) {
                echo '<p>' . wp_kses_post( $error ) . '</p>';
            }

            echo '</div>';

            // Clear
            delete_option( 'custom_notices' );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 That's an interesting technique -- thank you for sharing.